# Creating a hole using mirror, solidify, subdivision modifers

Tags: modeling

I want to create a hole at the top of [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eAd65.jpg) golf club head on [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VuNJs.jpg) face. There's a mirror modifier along the y axis.  With the [face removed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYXR6.jpg), I use [solidify](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZuVvr.jpg) and [subdivision](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rVch4.jpg) but see some artifacts. The same is true [without the mirror modifier](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WaWI5.jpg). How can I make this smoother?

[Screenshots](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C9KsJ.jpg).

Comment: You need to delete the extra edge after removing the top face

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by extra edge.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Before]
Your club has an edge along the YZ plane that you don't need. You probably used "Only Face" when you deleted the face.

[image: After]
After deleting the edge the modifiers work better.

Comment: The edge was the problem. Deleting it was the solution.